# Passing data to 2-byte unicode MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, postgresql, unicode, encoding

I have a web application that is based on PHP and PostgreSQL (built on Laravel). The web app PostgreSQL database uses UTF-8 encoding. At one point I have to pass data to an external MS SQL Server database that is hosted on another server. It works, however, the textual data in the MS SQL Server database is partially messed up and unreadable, especially where there are special characters involved. The MS SQL Server sysadmin told me that it uses a 2-byte Unicode encoding. I suppose I should convert accordingly.

Question - how to properly use this encoding and encode data before writing them to the MS SQL Server database?

Comment: You should use `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`

Comment: Use N for encoding in unicode when you are inserting. Like such `INSERT INTO table (textcolumn1, intcolumn1) VALUES (N'unicodé string', 1)`

Comment: @JacobH, It's better to use parameters instead of string literals

Comment: @MikhailLobanov the point does not change.

Comment: @Deez post your code and table definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with various encoding conversions, I finally found one that works for me:
`iconv('UTF-8', 'UCS-2LE', $string);`

Posting in case this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mb_convert_encoding` to change the character encoding:

```
$message = "Héllo";
$new_message = mb_convert_encoding($message, "UTF-16");
```

The example given in comments — `INSERT INTO table (textcolumn1, intcolumn1) VALUES (N'unicodé string', 1)` — is correct. Unfortunately there's no way to do this with prepared statements, e.g. `INSERT INTO table (textcolumn1, intcolumn1) VALUES (N?, ?)` will not work.